# Is there a Coffeescript for Java? In other words X gets compiled to Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, code-generation, coffeescript

Is there a language that gets compiled to Java code (not Byte code but Java .. so no Groovy, Scala, Jython, JRuby etc.)?

In other words is there a CoffeeScript for Java?

One of the major flaws I have against Java is that its so damn verbose and that it doesn't have multiple inheritance. It seems reasonably that one could just clean up the syntax add mixins/traits and closures through code generation.

Yeah its not elegant but coffeescript does it.

Comment: thanks god java does not have multiple inheritance

Comment: @mcabral I mean mixins or traits. Oh and I love repeating myself hundreds of times. Seriously I have to use AspectJ to keep Java OOP DRY or else I just have to paste code all over the place.

Comment: @mcabral: Multiple inheritance in itself is not a misfeature. The way C++ implements it has given it a bad name. Scala, for instance, implements multiple inheritance properly, and doesn't have the dreaded diamond problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care if a language compiles to Java instead of to bytecode? What would you do with that Java other than compiling it to bytecode?

Comment: Reasons: guaranteed compatibility with Java (ie some things in clojure,scala and groovy cannot really be called from Java), the possibility of custom AspectJ like macros or inline code generation that you can inspect, Java is easier to understand than bytecode, and its easier to inspect for performance problems and debugging.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yep, **Xtend**. It's a new language brought to you by the Eclipse folks: http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/

No multiple inheritance (that would be a fundamental change to Java semantics), but lots of syntactic sugar, just like CoffeeScript.

Also take a look at Mirah: http://www.mirah.org/

Comment: That is cool. I still think you should be able to do multiple inheritance similar to how I have to do it right now in AspectJ (http://stackoverflow.com/q/7403617/318174). It seems it should be easy to code generate MI.

Comment: Well, AspectJ doesn't compile to Java, strictly speaking. You can't really do AOP with pure Java code (efficiently).

Comment: Well maybe not all of AspectJ but the general wrapping of methods (before,after) and injecting additional methods through ITDs could easily be accomplished with code generation.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham Ah it looks like Xtend will do something close to what I want: http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/xtend/#extensionmethods

Comment: @TrevorBurnham Do you *have* to run Eclipse to use Xtend?  Because I'm not a big Eclipse user, but I am a huge coffeescript fan, and extending CS-like languages to Java would be a huge cognitive help for me.

Comment: @ElfSternberg I don't know; I've never used Xtend myself. I just write CoffeeScript. :)

Comment: @ElfSternberg In theory based on IvanLazarte answer you can use Coffeescript through Rhino. And yes you currently need to use Eclipse to use Xtend but they are actively working on a Maven plugin / Standalone.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, CoffeeScript compiling to Javascript means you can use coffeescript itself as a Java language.  With the latest CoffeeScript (1.1.3) you might need to use Rhino directly because it triggers a JS implementation bug in the current jdk, but outside of that, you should be good to use the compiled js files to interact with Java code.  :)

Comment: +1 An excellent point. However I like static typing slightly better than dynamic typing.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a pre-processor for text files that introduces `{`s and `}`s where there was indentation.  I called it:

- [Significant-White-Space (SWS)](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/significant-white-space)

It is nowhere near stable, and it doesn't address some of the other shortcuts you point out that Coffeescript offers, but it does work as a proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a transcompiler (just like CoffeeScript) to Java that supports multiple inheritance. It is very buggy and limited and does not allow many flexible formatting options, but it is still there and I would be more than happy if you checked it out or made a branch from it to improve it. I will probably add more features and fix many of the bugs, but for now, it at least works.

https://github.com/Philoprogrammer/Java-With-Multiple-Inheritance