# CoffeeScript for Java

Tags: java, jvm, coffeescript

CoffeeScript is so cool. If there is any language use the coffee syntax but running on jvm, like groovy, scala?
Python's syntax is not cool. i can't use so many **xx**,self in my code, that's ugly.

Comment: What do you mean by "cool" ???

Comment: @Andreas_D: ah yes, [U+2615 ☕](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2615/index.htm).

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Is there a CoffeeScript for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246132/is-there-a-coffeescript-for-java-in-other-words-x-gets-compiled-to-java)

Comment: I wrote a tool to strip and inject curly braces for a variety of languages.  I don't really recommended it for serious use.  https://github.com/joeytwiddle/significant-white-space/

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**.  [CoffeeScript compiles into plain old JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#usage), which [can be executed by modern JVMs (v6+)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html).

Incidentally, it's funny that you contrast the syntax of Python, since [both languages depend on whitespace as syntax](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/12/languages-on-javascript) (which is a controversial topic!).  Anyhoo, happy hacking!

**[Edit]** Here is a more useful introduction to [using JavaScript on the JVM](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/).

Comment: Holy mother of lord Jesus:) Javascript can now run on server side ?? I was going to downvote this guy . +1

Comment: @Shahzeb: that's barely the tip of the iceberg, [check out node.js](http://nodejs.org/)!

Comment: ...The link you provide doesn't mention "Javascript" anywhere on that page..?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: you're right!  I suppose it's "common knowledge" that JavaScript was the first (and only?) [ScriptEngine provided by the Sun JVM](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/).  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not specifically Coffeescript, [Mirah](http://www.mirah.org/) is a JVM language that compiles directly to JVM bytecode or Java source and requires **no runtime library** to run. Which makes it analogous to the way most people use Coffeescript. That is, avoiding the ugly semantic and syntactic elements of Javascript. Mirah is statically typed, yet its syntax borrows heavily from Ruby (Mirah is Javanese for Ruby).

While the language itself is still in its infancy, it's very possible to use it today. I've done most of my University homework using it where writing Java directly would have otherwise been required. I'm also poking at using it to develop for Android.

It does not look like Coffeescript, but it has the same goals and you may find it a good fit. Not to mention that Coffeescript syntax is also inspired somewhat on Ruby so the two share a common ancestor.