# Is there any standard Java dependency injection API based on static context?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Without depending from third-party frameworks, I would like to have a static context class to inject dependencies across different packages of my application. This way, I could avoid to pass the reference to a context object through several calls.

I have been looking at the standard Java APIs and found out about the `javax.naming.Context` interface and its implementation `javax.naming.InitialContext`. These can be used for dependency injection, but the context object would be non-static.

Basically, I would like to `set` a reference to an object from one package and `get` the same reference from another one. In other words, I would have a similar call in class (or package) A:

```
MyContext.setInstanceOf(MyInterface.class, new MyInterfaceImpl());
```

And the corresponding call in class (or package) B:

```
MyInterface obj = (MyInterface) MyContext.getInstanceOf(MyInterface.class);
```

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK no. Rolling your own static method should do the trick

Comment: Have you considered making your own context class, using [the singleton design pattern](https://www.callicoder.com/java-singleton-design-pattern-example/)?

Comment: Singleton is a bit of an anti pattern. If you really don't want to use a library (google guice) You can roll your own with only the java collections Map/HashTable provided you only need singleton scope and your dependencies don't contain cycles (Or you are willing to use setter based injection).

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Indeed, I also was thinking about making it a singleton. But first, I would avoid re-inventing the wheel if Java already provides a standard way.

Comment: @Keynan InitialContext already relies on hash tables. However, this way I would be obliged to pass the Map/HashTable/InitialContext object to whathever class needs it.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala I used the [cake pattern](https://medium.com/rahasak/scala-cake-pattern-e0cd894dae4e) I think that this is very pure and easy without a framework.

Because of the lack of traits in Java it is not so easiely applied to Java, but this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248766/cake-pattern-with-java8-possible) and [this blogpost](https://blackcatsolutions.co.uk/traits-cakes-and-java-8/) have examples implementing the cake pattern in Java 8.

Perhaps you give it a try.